# read "удерживает" дальнейшее исполнение программы

Tags: linux, c, debian

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
У меня есть кнопка, которая "привязана" к файлу, при нажатии кнопки в файл прописывается число 1. В случае если кнопка не нажата там лежит ноль.

Вот реализация считывания файла :

```
bool button_click()
{
    char *filename;
    int fd;
    //------------------------- prowerka
    fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY);
    asprintf(&filename, "%s/%s%d",DEV_INPUT_EVENT, EVENT_DEV_NAME,1);

    if (!filename)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    printf("buttin_klick tyt \n");

    if ((fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        perror("evtest");
        if (errno == EACCES && getuid() != 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "You do not have access to %s. Try "
                            "running as root instead.\n",
                    filename);
        return 0;
    }
    //-------------------------
    struct input_event ev[64];
    int i; int rd;
    fd_set rdfs;

    FD_ZERO(&rdfs);
    FD_SET(fd, &rdfs);

    printf("tutton_klik TYT 0 \n ");

    rd = read(fd, ev, sizeof(ev));

    printf("Button_klick TYT  0.1 \n");
    for (i=0;i<rd/sizeof(struct input_event);i++){
        if(ev[i].value == 1 ){
            printf("value %d\n", ev[i].value);
            // merchanie
            int b = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
            {
                if(b == 0)
                {brightness_file(b); usleep(30000); b=1;}
                else
                {brightness_file(b); usleep(30000); b=0;}
            }
            b=1; brightness_file(b);

            return 1;  
        }
        // если он не имеет единицы то
      if(ev[i].value == 0 ){
          printf("Open file rawen nuly \n");
          return 0;
       }
    }
    printf("Button_klic TYT 1 and ev.value =  %s \n",ev[i].value);
    return 0;
}
```

В коде есть одна проблема (либо если точнее не правильное восприятие) как только я до хожу до `rd = read(fd, ev, sizeof(ev));` то программа дальше " не идет " , а ждет пока я на кнопку нажму (что если честно я не совсем понимаю).

Думаю как эту проблему решить, думал через временные точки как вариант, но кажется что это не вариант.

Comment: судя по всему твой `read()` и есть ожидание появления события нажатия на кнопку в файле устройства (`/dev/input/event-что-то-там`), отсюда вопрос: что собственно программа должна делать, если ты __не__ нажмёшь кнопку? Вангую, что тебе нужно семейство вызовов `poll`/`select`, при этом ошмётки попыток использования последнего и остались в коде...

Comment: полинг, такой великий и ужастный, что проще уже сразу взять очередь событий и писать асинхронно. `glib` или `uv`. Я за uv потому как glib заставляет писать код в "своём" стиле, а uv компактен и податлив.

Comment: @Fat-Zer или неблокирующий read в бесконечном цикле и потоки)

Comment: @eri  `glib` я как понял это   [glib](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib), а что такое `uv` я не знаю . Мотете пожалуйста развернуть сиё значение

Comment: @timob256, [libuv](http://libuv.org/)... но с великим и ужасным полингом всё равно разобраться советую... а уж потом сказать «да вертел я всё это» и найти себе библиотечку поприятней (или написать свою), чтобы его инкапсулировать...

Comment: @timob256 http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/poll.html?highlight=uv_poll_init вот этой штукой заменить всю эту реализацию можно.

Comment: потом ждешь UV_READABLE и выполняется колбэк с ифами. пока ждем кнопку можно выполнять програмку мелкими кусочками. например паралельно ждать другой файл или рисовать что-то на экране.

Comment: @Fat-Zer только у меня проблема появилась , как в [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/) я как-то в QtCreator-e (Ubuntu) не нашёл, да и до качать через `sudo apt-get libuv(либо множество вариаций названий этой библиотеки).`  увы не вышло. У меня есть только  `pthread.h`

Comment: @timob256, в дебиано-бубунтах пакет называется `libuv1`... не забудь заодно `-dev` поставить... на будущее `apt-cache search libuv` в помощь... `pthread.h` к теме ни как не относится... но мой совет разобраться сначала с семейством вызовов `poll/select` на азах; примеров в сети много, обычно они идут в контексте сетевых сокетов...

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, это из-за того, что у вас в цикле и во вложенном в нем один и тот же итератор

```
        if(ev[i].value == 1 ){
            printf("value %d\n", ev[i].value);
            // merchanie
            int b = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
            {
                if(b == 0)
                {brightness_file(b); usleep(30000); b=1;}
                else
                {brightness_file(b); usleep(30000); b=0;}
            }
            b=1; brightness_file(b);

            return 1;  
        }
        // если он не имеет единицы то
      if(ev[i].value == 0 ){
          printf("Open file rawen nuly \n");
          return 0;
       }
```

Рекомендую заменить i на j или тому подобное

Даже если основная проблема не в этом, это все равно поздней всплывет.

Comment: Не уверен ,что это будет создавать проблемы сейчас, поскольку во внутреннем for итератор переобъявляется и перекрывает внешний. Но... В любом случае это потенциальный источник ошибки, так делать однозначно не стоит.